# how to install python libraries upon creation of ai platform notebooks

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I want to use "Select a script to run after creation" when I create a notebook instance in GCP.

Specifically, I want to use it to install python packages.

What kind of script (extension and contents) do I need to write?

Comment: This is the post startup script. This takes a shell script as parameter. (i.e conda install x)

Answer (score 1):

This will be an example of Post startup script that installs Voila.
Save this file in a GCS bucket and when creating the Notebook, define the path, for example:

```
gcloud notebooks instances create nb-1 \
'--vm-image-project=deeplearning-platform-release' \
'--vm-image-family=tf2-latest-cpu' \
'--metadata=post-startup-script=gs://ai-platform-notebooks-tools/install-voila.sh' \
'--location=us-central1-a'
```

Script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
# Installs Voila in AI Platform Notebook

function install_voila() {
  echo 'Installing voila...'
  /opt/conda/condabin/conda install -y -c conda-forge ipywidgets ipyvolume bqplot scipy
  /opt/conda/condabin/conda install -y -c conda-forge voila
  /opt/conda/bin/jupyter lab build
  systemctl restart jupyter.service || echo 'Error restarting jupyter.service.'
}

function download_samples() {
  echo 'Downloading samples...'
  cd /home/jupyter
  git clone https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila

}

function main() {
  install_voila || echo 'Error installing voila.' 
  download_samples || echo 'Error downloading voila samples.' 
}

main
```